# Make up-votes to questions worth 10 points again as they get so few votes?

Tags: discussion, questions, voting

I read that in the past the up-votes given to questions were worth 10 points just as the up-votes to answers are. However, after changing that moderators started encouraging users to vote more on questions, as they were getting so little attention. They even put that pop-up box that shows up after you've voted on X answers consecutively. So, if the community doesn't learn to vote more on questions, why not make the weight of up-votes go back to 10 points each?

Comment: On the main site, good answers are more important than good questions. People who want to know things go where people who know things are. That's also why question scres don't count towards your tag scores. It doesn't make you an expert if you post two dozen moderately good questions about a certain topic.

Comment: [Related topic on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115280/should-rewards-for-asking-good-questions-be-improved).

Comment: [Announcement blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/important-reputation-rule-changes/) when this was introduced.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I disagree.

I feel that questions are only worth 5 points. You're requesting information, needing to find an answer. Sure it might be a good question, but is a well written question worth as much as a big, well written, detailed answer? I don't think so.

Reputation is meant to show your knowledge and expertise. By giving more reputation to questions, it isn't showing reputation in the way it should be used.

Answers qualities are greater than that of a question, and should continue to be rewarded as such

Comment: How come you're always so quick to answer (and criticise) all my questions, Mr. Sheehan?

Comment: @the.midget Im very active on meta. You tagged this with [meta-tag:discussion], so I stated my opinion :)